# ([ngmodel]) object does not refresh data when it is changed in a method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

everybody,

I hope you'll help me with my problem.

I'm currently generating a set of inputs through a JSON.
If I modify the data in the web interface, there is no problem.

The problem comes when the value of any input, I modify it in the component, in a function for example.

It doesn't detect the changes. I have searched for information here, but I have not found the solution yet.

I leave you a link where you can see the code and the problem I have.

[Stackblitz Proyect Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-error-refresh-data-zprjnu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use proper bindings in the template:

to set the value `[ngModel]="form[inputs.value.name] || inputs.value.default"`, that allows to use the default value.

to update the value we need to listen to the output `(ngModelChange)="form[inputs.value.name] = $event"`.

```html
<input
  matInput
  type="number"
  id={{inputs.value.name}}
  [ngModel]="form[inputs.value.name] || inputs.value.default"
  (ngModelChange)="form[inputs.value.name] = $event"
  placeholder={{inputs.value.minimum}}
  min={{inputs.value.minimum}}
  max={{inputs.value.maximum}}
  step={{inputs.value.step}}
  matTooltip="{{inputs.value.title}}: {{inputs.value.description}}"
  matTooltipPosition="before"
  style="text-align: right;"
/>
```

Comment: a question, with your solution as long as there is no change in the inputs, the form object, this empty, does not have the default values. How can I have the form object with the default values even if the user does not make changes in the inputs?

Comment: for this you need to update the component's class to set default values into `form` in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Thanks again, I did this. `ngOnInit() {
    for (let variable in this.json.properties){
      this.form[variable]=this.json.properties[variable].default;
      
    }
  }` and remove `|| inputs.value.default` [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-error-refresh-data-zprjnu)